# How to find edges with Spring Data ArangoDB

Tags: spring-data, arangodb, aql

When using AQL directly to find edge documents, with a query like

```
FOR x IN coll1ToColl2 FILTER x._from == 'coll1/1234' RETURN x
```

the expected edge documents are returned, but when supplying `'coll1/1234'` to a Spring Data ArangoDB repository query method like:

```
@Query("FOR x IN coll1ToColl2 FILTER x._from == @from RETURN x")
Iterable<Coll1ToColl2> findEdgesFromColl1(@Param("from") String from);
```

the response is `null`.

How can edges be retrieved with Spring Data ArangoDB?

I'm using version `3.1.1` of the framework against version `3.4.0` of the database.

Comment: Hi, you may want to try a simple `RETURN @var` to see whats happening. Please note that when referencing collections in AQL-Queries, they are referenced via double-@ - `FOR x IN @@col RETURN x` => { '@col' : 'collectionname'}

Comment: What would the `@var` reference?
Now I have a repository method like:
`@Query("FOR x IN @@edgeCol FILTER x._from == @from RETURN x")
    Iterable<T> findEdgesByFrom(@Param("from") String from, @Param("@edgeCol") Class<?> edgeCollection);`

Comment: `@var` is a reference to `var` in the bind values. If this fixes your problems, please answer your question with that, and accept it.

Comment: Haven't arrived at the solution yet:  Are you suggesting I try something like:  `@Query("FOR x IN @@edgeCol RETURN @var") Iterable<T> findEdgesByFrom(@Param("var") String from, @Param("@edgeCol") Class<?> edgeCollection);` ?

Comment: this should only give you lists of your `var`- bindvariable in the size of the edge collection? Hint: you can also try this out in the webinterface, and later on add it to a programm.